# Is it necessary to have default.aspx in your project and as a starting page in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have created an empty web project and added a web form named `crud.aspx`.
When I run the web app it says `defualt.aspx` was not found.
so I created an `default.aspx`.

Now the problem is that it opens `defualt.aspx` as a starting page however, I want to open `crud.aspx` as a starting page.

Right clicking the `crud.aspx` and setting it to starting page did not helped!

Also it would be super nice if I could get rid of `default.aspx` entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested. See if this will work. In web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear/>
            <!--first preference-->
            <add value="default.aspx"/>
            <!--show second preference if first file is not found-->
            <add value="home.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
...
```

Try just adding the one page you want.

https://faragta.com/asp.net-web-forms/set-default-start-page-for-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of my **web.config**, which fixed my problem provided by **wazz** (**the accepted answer**).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

 <!--what i added becuase of the stack overflow answer start01-->
  
  <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
          <files>
              <clear/>
              <!--first preference-->
              <add value="CRUD.aspx"/>
              <!--show second preference if first file is not found-->
              <add value="default.aspx"/>
          </files>
      </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  
 <!-- ended01-->
  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```